# Null nested fields in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, null, nested, field, google-bigquery

I'm trying to upload a json file to BigQuery contaning a nested field which is null but it's not accepting.

I tried a lot of different syntax but I always got the error:

`File: 0 / Offset:0 / Line:1 / Column:410, missing required field(s)`

I tried to sent the value as many different values listed below and even ommiting it...

`"quotas": []
"quotas": null
"quotas": "null"
etc...`

The schema definition...

 `[..]
        "name": "quotas",
        "type": "record",
        "mode": "repeated",
        "fields":[

            {
                "name": "service",
                "type": "string",
                "mode": "nullable"
            }, 
                        [..]
                 ]
[..]`

Comment: Can you provide a job id for the failing job?

Comment: @JordanTigani - The job id is **nbr-data-storage:job_q1yZqkeKRgpeXUdwK5ScL6lZr2Y** Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell in the logs for the import worker for that job, the line in question is missing a required field (the field name starts with "msi"). The line is otherwise well-formatted from what I can tell.
I've filed a bug that BigQuery should give the name of the required field or fields that are missing to make this easier to debug in the future.

Comment: You're correct! The missing required field was a different one and has no relationship with the nested field, it was a wrong assumption I did. Sure, it would be very helpful to have the missing required field(s) in these cases, probably everyone would be able to fix by themselves. Thanks so much!